# Proving or disproving: $\frac{O(f(n))}{O(g(n))}=\frac{\Omega(f(n))}{\Omega(g(n))}$

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

Let $f,g$ be positive functions. Prove or disprove: $$
\frac{O(f(n))}{O(g(n))}=\frac{\Omega(f(n))}{\Omega(g(n))}
$$
I can't seem to figure out this statement. I could not think of an example that disproves it. I also could not find a way to prove it. How should I solve it?

Comment: I don't even believe that the quotient of two $O$ or $\Omega$ notations is well-defined (particularly since dividing by $0$ will be happening constantly). But to the extent that this is meaningful, just considering $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ to be powers of $n$, and remembering that neither $O$ nor $\Omega$ exactly pins down the growth of a function (for example, $n^2$ is both $O(n^3)$ and $\Omega(n)$), should be enough to refute it.

Answer (score 0):

Big O's on the LHS can be arbitrarily small. Big Omega's on the RHS can be arbitrarily big. It is easy to construct counterexamples following this logic.